# Can I visualise the world by how much it costs to fly there?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, maps

I'd like to compare potential destinations by visualising how much it costs to fly there - say one colour for it costing less than A$1000 to fly there from Sydney, another colour for A$1000 to A$2000, and so on.

Are there any tools that easily enable me to do that?

[Fare Compare](http://www.farecompare.com/maps/#/) gives me a list of prices, but it isn't colour-coded for easy visualisation.

Comment: For geographic visualisations of ad-hoc data, my first thought would be [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), but I don't know if you can get the fare data into that easily

Comment: I'm not sure how you would color-code such a map, given that there is so much variability in airfares. $900 is a good price for a walkup NYC-QLA, it's highway robbery if you're booking two months in advance.

Comment: And also some of the lowest fares are not something you really want to do anyways. Say, would you really like to fly from New York to some place in Western Europe with three stops?

Comment: It also varies by day and hour.  From Sydney to Singapore you can get for 200 sometimes, but at other times it costs more than that to fly to Melbourne.

Comment: I would like to see a distorted globe with that information. At times I can fly to Japan for about the same as flying halfway across Canada (10,000 km vs. 2500km) .

Answer (score 2):

The only tool I can think which does something like that, in a way, is SkyScanner.

If you insert From, Dates and no destinations it gives you an ordered list of fares, so even if it's not subdivided by color you still can go by "level" just scrolling down and up the page.

If instead you insert From and To and no Dates, you get a nice calendar with fares coloured up by range.

---

Note: what you are asking is quite doable, and make a lot of sense -I don't agree much with the comments, you just want fares shown by a custom range. And, from a computer's programmer point of view, generating it is not even complicated (a couple days of work at worst); why don't you just write an email to FareCompare to ask for it?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "doable". The visualization is straight forward enough, however the data itself is very noisy. Fares are very volatile and only weakly correlated with location and distance.  And it changes very quickly over time

Comment: Its easily hackable with monkeyscript; but will need to be done individually for each site.